# chrome status bar disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

as of last week I had a status bar in chrome.  i know it's not on full time, but it does show up when necessary (or at least it did)

it was useful for 2 things

- page loading status
- link hover info

not sure what happened, but it's gone and i can't find any settings for it.

i did not install any extensions to have it in the past.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is a bug, try this:

- Open Chrome Settings
- Select "Show Advanced Settings"
- Scroll down to "System"
- un-check "Use hardware acceleration when available"

---

As I said in the comments this is a Chrome bug ([Issue 345698](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345698#c7)) and there is no actual/perfect solution to this, one can only wait till the Chrome Developers fix the problem.

Comment: interesting.. that worked. then i checked it, and it went away again...

Comment: So is it working now ?

Comment: yes, when i disable hardware acceleration?.. WTH????

Comment: Hahaha, yeah it is a weird bug. But I think they will fix it in the next updates. Hey don't forget to +1  ;)

Comment: actually this worked for a little while, but status went away again.. seems like i have to toggle that setting daily now ..

Comment: this is still an issue.. toggling that switch works temporarily but status disappears soon after. I tried updating to the latest chrome too .. currently on Version 33.0.1750.146 m

Comment: This is a bug and it does not mean that it will be fixed any soon. There is no actual solution to this.

Comment: @SonicSoul, like Devid said, there is no way to fix it for now. You can try complaining to the devs to fix it, but Google is notorious for ignoring user feedback. `what i am looking for is a way to revert to a version of chrome that doesn't have this bug.` You can get an old version from FileHippo, but you have to make sure to disable automatic-updates (which Google makes difficult). Regardless, I don’t see why you gave harry the bounty even though Devid had already said it was a bug over a month earlier.

Comment: Worked for me but made video playback in the browser look awful.

Comment: WTF?  I'm mystified as to how "Hardware acceleration" is connected to something like this.  But never mind, I don't even want to know.  I am having this problem, on some pages but not others.  Right now I have two tabs open.  One shows me the links when I hover, the other does not.  :-(

Answer (score 15):

This bug has a long history in Chrome of appearing several times, as well as being
fixed several times. Turning off hardware acceleration sometimes fixes it,
but perhaps only incidentally because it restarts Chrome.
Reinstalling Chrome sometimes also helped momentarily.

It was last "fixed" in version 34.0.1838.2 :
[Issue 341879: REGRESSION: Status bar/bubble and tooltips no longer appear](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341879),
but was observed to be triggered again when any drop-down list was used.

Then came
[Issue 345698: REGRESSION: URL Not Displaying in Lower-Left Corner When Hovering Over Link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345698#c7)
in which the latest entry from 2014-03-11 seems to promise a final solution.
The issue is marked as Closed on Mars 10.

I suggest waiting for these fixes to find their way into the official version.
Better keep an eye on Issue 345698 and relaunch it if necessary.
The bug has to be fixed in Chrome itself, as there is no workaround possible for it
except restarting Chrome.

It should be noted that this is not one bug that reappears again and again,
but rather multiple bugs having the same effect.
There is no guarantee that the bugs fixed in
Issues 345698 and 341879 are the last of their kind.

Comment: i guess what i am looking for is a way to revert to a version of chrome that doesn't have this bug.. since not everyone with latest chrome has this issue? there's probably something else that's triggering the bug.

Comment: Chrome has always had these bugs. For example see one more [Issue 123901](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123901) from April 2012, apparently marked as Closed but without solution(!). If you don't want to restart Chrome every time the bar is stuck in the off state, your only solution is to use another browser until Issue 345698 makes it into the release. But again, no guarantee that your problem is not actually another bug that's not been treated yet or one that the developers decided to ignore because too complicated to fix.

Answer (score 4):

I run Chrome tiled, side by side and notice the status bar disappearing from time to time.

To get it back, I create a new empty tab and then drag my already open tabs to that new empty one.  The status bar reappears.  I can then close the empty one where the status bar had disappeared and retile to get everything arranged the way I want it.

Comment: thanks, but it would be much quicker to just close your chrome, open a new window and press ctrl+shift+t .. this will re-open all the tabs from previous session ;)

Comment: +1 this is actually a better solution for times when you have 15 tabs or so open and don't want to reload all of them and if you want to preserve state.

Answer (score 4):

I found out a "workaround", if you right-click the link, for the moment you hold the button pressed you can see the address, hope it helps.
cheers

Comment: awesome! works with **holding** left click too, but right is better. :)

Comment: not working for me with a right click(hold) or left click(hold), but a left drag shows the label and the link in a little box. chrome  66.0.3359.181. OK that is annoying, when I went to check the version it updated and now the relaunched Chrome has the status bar back.

Answer (score -5):

It is very easy and simple. Just press and hold the Ctrl and scroll up or down with the mouse, the Status bar will appear on the upper right corner. Then you can adjust to zoom in or out the page.

Comment: That's not the status bar, that's a zoom control.